# Setting up PSake

Tags: powershell, psake

Does anybody know or have a link to how I set up psake to run through powershell?

I have absolutely no idea and I can find nothing to tell me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/psake/downloads/list).  Here are some examples of its use:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/30/on-psake.aspx
http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/IntroducingPsake.aspx

The 2.0 version of PSake is a PowerShell module which requires PowerShell 2.0. Extract the contents of the PSake ZIP into $env:Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSake.  Then you import it like so:

```
Import-Module PSake
```

Define a "properties" hashtable and then start using its exported commands like Task in your build scripts.

Comment: Import-Module is one way.  
http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=PowerShell describes this way:

you can copy the psake.psm1 into a folder called psake into the "Modules" folder in your profile directory (you may have to create it if it's not there) or your machine-wide "Modules" directory: 

i.e. Profile Directory: 

C:\Users\Jorge\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\psake 

i.e. Machine-wide Modules folder: 

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\psake